# How to hide new item button in toolbar but keep edit

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, list

So I have a list where I have applied unique permission and user can "Edit" an item but cannot "Add" an item. Normally this should have handled by SharePoint and it shouldn't show "new item" link but keep "edit" button but apparently that's not the case (I guess it's SharePoint being SharePoint).

Once you remove "Add" item permission then the whole line which says "new item or edit this list" becomes hidden. So I was thinking is there a way to only hide "new item"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add the style, given below to Content Editor Web Part to achieve the hiding of the add link. But this will still leave "or" in the page. If we need remove "or". We need to use javascript to cover the html code.

```
 <style>  
 #idHomePageNewItem {  
 display:none;  
 }  
 </style>
```